# Solving recurrence relation $T(n)\le T(0.9n)+T(0.2n)+O(n)$

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to solve the following recurrence relation

> $$T(n)\le T\left(\frac{9}{10}n\right)+T\left(\frac{1}{5}n\right)+\text{O}(n)$$

According to book it should be that $T(n)=\text{O}(n^2)$. I tried to prove by induction. Assume that for any $k<n$ the claim holds, i.e $T(k)\le ck^2$. Now I have \begin{align*}T(n)\le T\left(\frac{9}{10}n\right)+T\left(\frac{1}{5}n\right)+\text{O}(n) \le \frac{81}{100}c n^2+\frac{1}{25}c n^2+\text{O}(n)\\=\frac{85}{100}cn^2+\text{O}(n)\le cn^2 \end{align*}

Is this correct?

Comment: seems correct to me.

Comment: But you should not have those O(n).

Comment: Is $n$ allowed to take any positive real value?

Comment: @almagest, we can assume that $n$ is sufficiently large. Why do you think I should not have O(n)? This is the recurrence relation. I can't just delete it with no reason.